# How do I limit the user from entering the wrong format for my time field

Tags: python, regex, datetime, time, python-re

I have already searched this question on stack overflow, but didn't find something that helped me or simply didn't understand them. What I want is a way to affirm that the user has entered the time in the following format `hh:mm-hh:mm`. example:`13:30-14:30`. I don't mind the format being 12hr or 24hr. Also the time needs to be restricted, in the sense that minutes should not go beyond 59 and hours should not go beyond 23. I've seen solutions that make use of regex, and I've seen the official documentation as well, but I find it hard to understand. So if anyone is using regex for an answer I don't mind accepting it as long as the answer explains the meaning of the regex expression.
`pattern=r'[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'`
This was my attempt, but as it is clearly visible this has a lot of bugs. According to this expression,
`29:58-29:59`
is a valid time, which of course isn't.

Comment: @anubhava I have added my attempt in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex will just make it more complicated. Use [time.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) instead to parse if the time is correct. With the usage of the `time` module, you can highly customize this to read 12h or 24h format, read the string "AM" or "PM", etc.

Then if you wish to also validate if the 2nd time is greater than the 1st time, you can easily use the functionalities in the `time` module to perform this too.

```
import time


for data in [
    "13:30-14:30",
    "13:61-14:30",
    "13:30-14:99",
    "00:00-23:59",
    "00:0023:59",
    "XY:10-12:30",
    "01:44-06:00",
    "-11:10-12:30",
    "11:10-12:30",
    "26:10-34:12",
]:
    print(data)

    # Parse as 24h format
    try:
        start_time, _, end_time = data.partition("-")
        start_time = time.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M")
        end_time = time.strptime(end_time, "%H:%M")
    except Exception as error:
        print("\tThe time is invalid in 24h format!")
    else:
        print("\tThe time is valid in 24h format")

    # Parse as 12h format
    try:
        start_time, _, end_time = data.partition("-")
        start_time = time.strptime(start_time, "%I:%M")
        end_time = time.strptime(end_time, "%I:%M")
    except Exception as error:
        print("\tThe time is invalid in 12h format!")
    else:
        print("\tThe time is valid in 12h format")
```

**Output:**

```
13:30-14:30
    The time is valid in 24h format
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
13:61-14:30
    The time is invalid in 24h format!
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
13:30-14:99
    The time is invalid in 24h format!
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
00:00-23:59
    The time is valid in 24h format
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
00:0023:59
    The time is invalid in 24h format!
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
XY:10-12:30
    The time is invalid in 24h format!
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
01:44-06:00
    The time is valid in 24h format
    The time is valid in 12h format
-11:10-12:30
    The time is invalid in 24h format!
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
11:10-12:30
    The time is valid in 24h format
    The time is valid in 12h format
26:10-34:12
    The time is invalid in 24h format!
    The time is invalid in 12h format!
```

For the possible formats, see:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes
- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a 12hr format as well. Your solution above worked, but i was just curious to know whether it would be possible.

Comment: Yes it can, I updated my answer. You can parse anything that you can see in the `strptime` documentations which I have linked in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a regex solution then this regex may work for you:

```sh
^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)-(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeFwdS/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):`: Hours from `00` to `23` followed by a `:`
- `(?:[0-5]\d)-`: Minutes from `00` tp `59` followed by a `-`
- `(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):`: Hours from `00` to `23` followed by a `:`
- `(?:[0-5]\d)`: Minutes from `00` tp `59`
- `$`: End

Comment: what is the purpose of "?:" i.e. diff in (?:[01]\d|2[0-3]) and ([01]\d|2[0-3])

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. If we don't want to capture something it is more efficient to use a non-capture group.

Comment: I would go with the date-time API as shown in the accepted answer. However, this regex solution is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Niel Godfrey Ponciano's answer solves the problem but I would make the following modifications:

```
user_input = user_input.replace(' ', '')
```

You don't want the time parsing fail due to spaces and shouldn't bug the user over a minor error either.

I would personally choose `datetime.strptime()` over `time.strptime()` due to more convenience functions. There's nothing wrong with the latter though.

Comment: Thanks, I did face the problem, and I had used the same code when I faced the error. I have upvoted so that others who might face the same problem can benefit from your modification.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern (in 24 hour format): `/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4])\:([0-5][0-9])\-([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])\:([0-5][0-9])$/g`

**Pattern description:**

**For hour:** If the first number is 0 or 1 then second number can be between 0-9 (Like 01, 09, 18 and ...) or if the first number is 2 then second number can be between 0-3 (Like 20, 21, 22 and 23)

**For Minute:** If the first number is between 0-5 the second number can be between 0-9 (Like all minute numbers).

Answer (score 0):

We can use regex here too:

```
([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EeImIa/1

Comment: Cons part of this pattern is that we can't validate whether the end time is greater or not than the first string.